# Desktop Notification for Java-based webapp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, web-applications

I have a web-app which is based on Java. It uses spring-hibernate framework and struts at some places.

The front-end is coded in javascript and html.

The web-app is a platform where people can file in complaints against various brands. There is also a framework to scrape complaints from social feeds.

I want to build a desktop notification system for my webapp. The notif-system should be able to show a notification every time a new complaint comes in.

I want to know what framework should I use and how do I go about building a Desktop notifications system for incoming complaints.

I did some digging around. There is chrome.notifications API and Java API for WebSocket protocols. But I'm not sure they are definitely the things I want to use.

I would like to know how I can go about it.

Comment: What's wrong with the HTML5 notifications API? it should be perfect for what you need

Comment: @drorb maybe because it's technology's specification has not stabilized yet?

Comment: this is a good point. It should probably be part of your question. Personally I believe that it is better to use a solution which is specifically meant to solve your problem even if it is not final